# Issue with filtering data using Droplink target item ID in Sitecore 10.2 XP0 GraphQL search query

Tags: graphql, sitecore, headless

I am currently working on a Sitecore 10.2 XP0 project and using GraphQL for performing search queries. However, I am facing an issue when trying to filter the data using the where clause with a Droplink field's target item ID.

Here is the sample GraphQL query I'm using:

```
query pressRel {
      PressRelease: search (
        where: {
          name: "_path"
          value: "{6271A7D0-0F4C-45E4-9F5C-10A7D3E0E659}"
          operator: EQ
          AND: [
                {
                  name: "_template"
                  value: "{70322B40-9928-46CF-B952-9B86C60751E8}"
                  operator: EQ
                }
                {
                  name: "year"
                  value: "b4113915-08d1-4628-8ef7-380ff6ec9777"
                  operator: CONTAINS
                }
                ]
          }
        first: 10
      ) {
        Total: total,
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNext
        }
        Results: results {
          ...on News {
            title: title {
              value
            }
            Year: year {              
              jsonValue
              targetItem {
                fields {
                  value
                }
              }
            }            
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The issue specifically arises when I try to filter using the Droplink field's target item ID in the where clause. I have verified that the target item ID is correct.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly filter the data using the Droplink target item ID in the GraphQL search query for Sitecore 10.2 XP0.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you have curly braces around a UUID? `"{70322B40-9928-46CF-B952-9B86C60751E8}"` - shouldn't that just be `"70322B40-9928-46CF-B952-9B86C60751E8"`